# Como chamar uma função dentro de uma função anônima?

Tags: javascript

Segue o código:

`minhaFuncao();`

Aqui está o código:

```
$(function () {
    $.connection.hub.start().done(function () {
        function minhaFuncao() {
            alert("ok");
        }
    });
});
```

Eu recebo erro:

> minhaFuncao is not defined at HTMLFormElement.OnSuccess

Comment: Por quê está definido a função ali? O problema que definindo-a dentro de uma função anônima, ela deixa de existir quando a mesma termina de ser executada. Ou seja, quando fizer a chamada, ela não existirá, dando o erro. Não há explicação em definí-la dentro do evento `done`.

Comment: @MatheusMiranda por que você não faz contrário? Defina ela fora do `done` e chame ela como callback depois sem rescrevê-la.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O problema de definir a função dentro de uma função anônima é que a mesma pertencerá apenas ao contexto desta função, deixando de existir quando a função anônima terminar de executar. Se a questão é apenas chamar a função dentro da função anônima que trata o evento `done`, você pode definir a função desejada num contexto mais amplo e apenas chamá-la, como o exemplo abaixo.

```
$(function () {
    function minhaFuncao() {
        alert("ok");
    }

    $.connection.hub.start().done(function () {
        minhaFuncao();
    });
});
```

Desta forma, `minhaFuncao` está definida num contexto maior, existindo em qualquer parte do código dentro de `$(function () {...});` do jQuery.

> O exemplo a seguir foi produzido apenas para mostrar o funcionamento da lógica acima aqui no SOpt, uma vez que não conseguiria reproduzir o evento `$.connection.hub.start().done`, visto que depende de plugins de terceiros.

Para ver em funcionamento, basta fazer um exemplo mais simples:

```js
function minhaFuncao() {
  alert("ok");
}

$(function () {
  minhaFuncao();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

A própria função definida como contexto do jQuery é uma função anônima. Definindo sua função no contexto global, ela existirá ali também. Quando a página possuir o DOM carregado, uma alerta será exibido.

Comment: Acho que o termo "função anônima" não encaixa muito, porque a situação seria a mesma mesmo sendo uma função com nome definido. Não importa se a função é expressada (e ainda assim pode ter nome).

Comment: É o mesmo funcionamento, mas o AP perguntou explicitamente para funções anônimas. Por quê acha que "não encaixa muito"?

Comment: Verdade, não liguei muito para o título, apenas para o contexto.

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss, e o jQuery.when() ?

Comment: @MatheusMiranda, o que tem?

Comment: O problema era chamar um função que contém `done` correto ? Com `$.when` já é possível chamar uma função ? Segue exemplo em jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/h4JXs/5318/ Me corrija se eu estiver errado.

Comment: Não, o problema era definir uma função dentro de `done`, que não faz sentido. Não há problema algum em utilizar o `done`. O `when` é para trabalhar com *promises*, acredito que seria a mesma coisa que utilizar o `done` como está na pergunta. Acho que não faria muito sentido utilizar também.